# integral_constant vs constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Could you please explain, why integral_constant and constexpr approaches in the following example result in different behaviours?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Logger
{
//    template<typename Type>
//    using IsRawString =
//        std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<const char*, Type>::value || std::is_same<char*, Type>::value>;

    template<typename Type>
    constexpr bool IsRawString()
    {
        return std::is_same<const char*, Type>::value || std::is_same<char*, Type>::value;
    }

    template<typename Type, typename Enable = void>
    struct Traits
    {
        static const int Index = 1;
    };

    template<typename Type>
    struct Traits<Type, std::enable_if_t<IsRawString<Type>()>>
    {
        static const int Index = 2;
    };

    template<typename Type>
    struct Traits<Type, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<Type>::value && !IsRawString<Type>()>>
    {
        static const int Index = 3;
    };

};

int main()
{
    cout << Logger::Traits<int>::Index << endl
         << Logger::Traits<char*>::Index << endl
         << Logger::Traits<const char*>::Index << endl
         << Logger::Traits<void*>::Index << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

integral_constant approach https://ideone.com/WQy71r:

```
1
2
2
3
```

constexpr approach https://ideone.com/wPiM1m:

```
1
1
1
1
```

If I remove `Logger` struct and use `Traits` from the global scope, both approaches give the same result as for integral_constant inside struct (https://ideone.com/WGVuXE https://ideone.com/OpTbDm).

Comment: It shouldn't build at all for the constexpr **non-static** member function. The fact it even does is a GCC bug, I'd say.

Comment: To further stress the point, Clang gives a sane error http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/390e9c0c058b8a28

Comment: this version works, but there's actually two changes -- member function to `static constexpr`, and primary template to a forward declaration: not sure exactly why the behavior is changing and why you see `1 1 1 1` at all though. https://ideone.com/19V8wv

Comment: It seems, it's a gcc issue.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your `IsRawString()` declared as non `static` and it require class object for to be called.

When compiler try to generate `Logger::Traits<char*>::Index` and `Logger::Traits<const char*>::Index` it use **SFINAE**(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and reject wrong variants with your constexpr function. The first `Traits` form with `template<typename Type, typename Enable = void>` generates only. Try declare `IsRawString()` as `static` member function